# At what condition is the default constructor generated?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I have the following class:

```
class Tileset { //base class

public:
    static std::vector<Tileset*> list;
    virtual ~Tileset() = 0;

protected:
    std::vector<Tile> tiles_list;
    sf::Texture sheet;

private: //non copiable
    Tileset(const Tileset&);
    Tileset& operator=(const Tileset&);
};
```

where `sf::Texture` has a default constructor

From my understanding a default constructor should be generated since every member can be default-constructed too.
Yet I have a compiler error when I try to construct a derived object without calling a `Tileset` constructor.
Can someone explain why no default constructor is generated?

edit : forgot to mention that `Tile` class doesn't have a default constructor. I'm not sure if that changes anything

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585708/copy-constructor-and-default-constructor (for your copy constructor disables creation of default constructor problem)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A default constructor will be not be generated if any of the following are true

- There is a user defined constructor declared
- The type has a `const` or reference field

You declared a constructor hence C++ won't provide a default generated one.  In this case though all of the fields of `Tileset` have useful default constructors so defining a default constructor here is very easy

```
Tileset() { }
```

Comment: So the problem comes from my Tileset(const Tileset&); ? Yet it's not implemented on purpose (which the compiler won't know untill linking), so I think that it's unsolvable pre-C++11?

Comment: @lezebulon: Instead of declaring the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator private, you could inherit from a class with these declared private. That also has the advantage of making them inaccessible to members of your class.

Comment: I just tested : Tileset(const Tileset&) = delete;
shouldn't it work using this? Since i am not declaring any constructor that way

Comment: @lezebulon: Mike's base class is already implemented by Boost as `boost::noncopyable`.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't provide any constructor, only then the compiler generates the default constructor for your class. If you provide a constructor (even copy-constructor), then compiler will not generate the default constructor.

By "provide" I mean when you *declare* and "optionally" *define* a constructor in your class.

Answer (score 1):

From C++ spec, 12.1.5

> If there is no *user-declared* constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly declared. An *implicitly-declared* default constructor is an `inline public` member of its class.

Your `Tileset` class declared a constructor, hence C++ compiler did not declare an implicit constructor for you. The rationale for this behavior is that since you provided constructors that take parameters, you probably need these parameters in order to properly initialize an instance of your class. The assumption here is that if you wanted a default constructor in addition to a non-default one, you'd simply declare it.

Comment: @lezebulon Oops, there's only one :)