# How to retrieve a cv::Mat object from an object of this API class?

Tags: c++, opencv, observers

I am stuck trying to get a `cv::Mat` object from another class (third party code) into my main function.

I have a class:

FrameObserver.h

```
class FrameObserver : virtual public IFrameObserver
{
public:

    FrameObserver( CameraPtr pCamera, FrameInfos eFrameInfos, ColorProcessing eColorProcessing );
    cv::Mat m_ConvertImage;
    // This is our callback routine that will be executed on every received frame
    virtual void FrameReceivedLeft( const FramePtr pFrame );
    virtual void FrameReceivedRight(const FramePtr pFrame);
    void ProcessCvLeft(const FramePtr pFrame);
    void ProcessCvRight(const FramePtr pFrame);
    static cv::Mat FrameObserver::getCurrentFrame() { return currentFrame; }

private:
    static cv::Mat currentFrame;

#ifdef WIN32
    double      m_dFrequency;
#endif //WIN32
};

}}} // namespace AVT::VmbAPI::Examples
```

FrameObserver.cpp

```
void FrameObserver::ProcessCvLeft(const FramePtr pFrame)
{
    VmbUchar_t *pBuffer;
    VmbUint32_t FrameWidth;
    VmbUint32_t FrameHeight;

    pFrame->GetWidth(FrameWidth);
    pFrame->GetHeight(FrameHeight);
    pFrame->GetImage(pBuffer);

    ShowFrameInfos(pFrame);

    IplImage *img1 = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(
        FrameWidth,
        FrameHeight),
        IPL_DEPTH_8U,
        1);
    cvSetData(img1, pBuffer, img1->widthStep);

    cv::Mat copyimageL = cv::cvarrToMat(img1);

    currentFrame = copyimageL;  //copies to currentFrame here
}
```

Then I have main.cpp:

```
cv::Mat Mainframe;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
//I need to pull the currentFrame Mat stream into the frame Mat above.
}
```

What is the best way to do this? I have tried:

```
FrameObserver fo;
cv::Mat test = fo.currentFrame;
```

But it gives me the following error:

> no default constructor exists for class "FrameObserver"

Thank you.

Comment: Post the exact error message along with the line number and the relevant piece of code else there is little chance of helping you.

Comment: edited, code is psuedo, for simplicity.

Comment: **No pseudo code**. Post the exact C++ code you have come up with.

Comment: edited, with code. thanks!

Comment: Now you mentioned an error, which was a part of your problem. Edit the error message as well as the relevant code where it happens back in. Your problem can be solved by adding a getter method `cv::Mat FrameObserver::getCurrentFrame() { return currentFrame; }`. Make `FrameObserver::currentFrame` private or protected, since your'e violating encapsulation.

Comment: Great, now we need the line number, and the error message as a quote please. Precisely: which class is said to have no default constructor? There's no way to guess that from here.

Comment: Will edit now. I have added  the getter method to the header file, and moved currentFrame to Private. I see : Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static class cv::Mat FrameObserver::currentFrame"  on build.

Comment: You seem to have done smth wrong implementing my suggestion, so revert back to the initial state and post the error message you first received.

Comment: Can you now post the **complete** `class FrameObserver` declaration?

Comment: lesson to be learned here: don't run wild with misunderstood oop principles (wtf: virtual inheritance?)

Comment: @berak is there some rule that prevents generation of defaults c'tors in the presence of virtual inheritance or even simple inheritance?

Comment: @Ben still show us the declaration or at least the docs for `FrameObserver` if it's third party!

Comment: Why declare the the new members as `static`?!

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that FrameObserver is not mine. It is the sdk from my gige camera, and a little out of my c++ depth!

Comment: In that case, 1)don't modify it and 2)link to the docs for the class.

Comment: static, because if not i am back to 'a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object', and I cannot use FrameObserver fo; fo.currentFrame. Apologies for my idiocy.

Comment: Means you created as reference instead of a plain object member. No need to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as C++ goes, your mistake is that the class `FrameObserver` has no default constructor (i.e. a constructor that can be called without arguments). It's not defined explicitly, nor will it be generated, since another constructor has already been defined (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638527/at-what-condition-is-the-default-constructor-generated)). Thus, you can't write

```
FrameObserver fo;
```

Since this invokes the default constructor `FrameObserver::FrameObserver()` which (see above) is not present. Thus, you should create the `FrameObserver` object using the existing constructor with arguments `FrameObserver::FrameObserver( CameraPtr pCamera, FrameInfos eFrameInfos, ColorProcessing eColorProcessing );`

Now on to the actual problem. Since this class is a part of a supplied API, you shouldn't try to change it, rather learn to use it correctly. By the name of it, it appears to be an observer. Thus, you need to create an instance of it (a single one, at that), and *carefully read the docs* on how it's supposed to supply you frame data as a matrix. I don't know how exactly it works, but by common sense, since it's an "observer", it should automatically provide you with notifications about incoming frames. Again, have a close look at the documentation.

**Important edit:**

Here it is, look at the header:

```
// This is our callback routine that will be executed on every received frame
virtual void FrameReceivedLeft( const FramePtr pFrame );
virtual void FrameReceivedRight(const FramePtr pFrame);
```

By the looks of it, you are supposed to subclass `FrameObserver` and reimplement the two above functions. That means that the code to process or extract those frames must reside inside those routines in the subclass you're going to create.

Anyway, while the details may vary, the concept stays: the observer is going to call some methods on its own. You can only wait for it to call those methods and react accordingly. More precisely, you register your class object or function within the observer object, and then let the observer call those methods automatically. (It is said that you "subscribe to the notifications" provided by the observer).

Comment: @Ben I've added something above, take a look.

Comment: I better add subclasses to my reading material. thanks again.